# One way audio with WebRTC and Asterisk 15

Tags: webrtc

I have two ways audio when calling from a WebRTC client connected to Asterisk to my mobile phone, but when I call from the mobile phone to the WebRTC client the call is established and there is only one way audio: from the WebRTC client to the mobile phone.

I'm using Asterisk 15.6.1 installed on a VPS with static IP, the WebRTC client is a browser softphone using the SIP.js library, and I have a local phone number from Localphone.

My "pjsip.conf" relevant settings are:

```
[localphone]
type=registration
transport=transport-udp
outbound_auth=localphone
client_uri = sip:12345678@localphone.com:5060
server_uri = sip:localphone.com:5060
auth_rejection_permanent=no
contact_user=12345678

[localphone]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
username=12345678
password=mypassword

[localphone]
type=aor
max_contacts=100
contact=sip:12345678@localphone.com

[localphone]
type=endpoint
transport=transport-udp
context=localphone-inc
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
rtcp_mux=yes
ice_support=yes
direct_media=no
from_user=12345678
from_domain=localphone.com
outbound_auth=localphone
aors=localphone

[localphone]
type = identify
endpoint = localphone
match = 140.153.72.56


; This is the WebRTC client

[1652]
type=aor
max_contacts=100

[auth1652]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
username=1652
password=complicatedpassword

[1652]
type=endpoint
context=localphone-pjsip
aors=1652
auth=auth1652
transport=transport-wss
webrtc=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
dtls_cert_file=/etc/asterisk/key/asterisk.pem
dtls_private_key=/etc/asterisk/key/asterisk.key

[1652]
type = identify
endpoint = 1652
match = 123.123.123.123  ; the public IP of the VPS
```

The Asterisk debug log doesn’t show errors. The SIP session looks like this:

```
<--- Received SIP request (1175 bytes) from UDP:140.153.72.56:5060 --->
INVITE sip:136.46.324.75:5060 SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:140.153.72.56;lr=on;ftag=gK086bb5a7>
Record-Route: <sip:126.219.52.41;lr;ftag=gK086bb5a7>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 140.153.72.56;branch=z9hG4bK356c.5360dbb7.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 126.219.52.41:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK356c.10463da.0
From: <sip:10782172281@126.219.52.41>;tag=gK086bb5a7
To: <sip:13051079265@localphone.com>;tag=514dc3ba-68ed-42ff-9733-bd65b8ebb7c7
Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56
CSeq: 63984 INVITE
Max-Forwards: 12
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,REGISTER,REFER,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,PRACK,UPDATE,OPTIONS,MESSAGE,PUBLISH
Accept: application/sdp, application/isup, application/dtmf, application/dtmf-relay,  multipart/mixed
Contact: <sip:126.219.52.41;vbdid=941.29056c13>
Supported: timer
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
Min-SE: 90
Content-Length:   239
Content-Disposition: session; handling=required
Content-Type: application/sdp

v=0
o=Sonus_UAC 13229 650067 IN IP4 199.199.12.56
s=SIP Media Capabilities
c=IN IP4 199.199.12.54
t=0 0
m=audio 40808 RTP/AVP 0 100
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:100 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:100 0-15
a=sendrecv
a=maxptime:20

       > 0x7fddf001b170 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 199.199.12.54:40808
<--- Transmitting SIP response (1062 bytes) to UDP:140.153.72.56:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 140.153.72.56;rport=5060;received=140.153.72.56;branch=z9hG4bK356c.5360dbb7.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 126.219.52.41:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK356c.10463da.0
Record-Route: <sip:140.153.72.56;lr;ftag=gK086bb5a7>
Record-Route: <sip:126.219.52.41;lr;ftag=gK086bb5a7>
Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56
From: <sip:10782172281@126.219.52.41>;tag=gK086bb5a7
To: <sip:13051079265@localphone.com>;tag=514dc3ba-68ed-42ff-9733-bd65b8ebb7c7
CSeq: 63984 INVITE
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
Require: timer
Contact: <sip:136.46.324.75:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REGISTER, REFER, MESSAGE
Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
Server: Asterisk PBX 15.6.1
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   234

v=0
o=- 13229 650069 IN IP4 136.46.324.75
s=Asterisk
c=IN IP4 136.46.324.75
t=0 0
m=audio 10010 RTP/AVP 0 100
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:100 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:100 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv

       > 0x7fddf001b170 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 199.199.12.54:40808 as source
<--- Received SIP request (411 bytes) from UDP:140.153.72.56:5060 --->
ACK sip:136.46.324.75:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 140.153.72.56;branch=z9hG4bK356c.5360dbb7.2
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 126.219.52.41:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK356c.10463da.2
From: <sip:10782172281@126.219.52.41>;tag=gK086bb5a7
To: <sip:13051079265@localphone.com>;tag=514dc3ba-68ed-42ff-9733-bd65b8ebb7c7
Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56
CSeq: 63984 ACK
Max-Forwards: 12
Content-Length: 0


<--- Received SIP request (428 bytes) from WSS:152.231.162.25:53283 --->
BYE sip:asterisk@mail.example.com:5060;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS qae9g3ug98cm.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8418203
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:10782172281@mail.example.com>;tag=46b408fd-815a-49c1-b337-74ee894d6e44
From: "Grant Brandon" <sip:6l78pghi@152.231.162.25>;tag=1l7sldm3o2
Call-ID: 4b8d773b-243b-4e97-9962-efc4d55eb0de
CSeq: 27946 BYE
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.8
Content-Length: 0


<--- Transmitting SIP response (376 bytes) to WSS:152.231.162.25:53283 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS qae9g3ug98cm.invalid;rport=53283;received=152.231.162.25;branch=z9hG4bK8418203
Call-ID: 4b8d773b-243b-4e97-9962-efc4d55eb0de
From: "Grant Brandon" <sip:6l78pghi@152.231.162.25>;tag=1l7sldm3o2
To: <sip:10782172281@mail.example.com>;tag=46b408fd-815a-49c1-b337-74ee894d6e44
CSeq: 27946 BYE
Server: Asterisk PBX 15.6.1
Content-Length:  0


    -- Channel PJSIP/601-00000003 left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f59afd46-1e16-4f47-9a9d-59c11987cc77>
    -- Channel PJSIP/localphone-00000002 left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f59afd46-1e16-4f47-9a9d-59c11987cc77>
  == Spawn extension (localphone-pjsip, 601, 1) exited non-zero on 'PJSIP/localphone-00000002'
<--- Transmitting SIP request (487 bytes) to UDP:140.153.72.56:5060 --->
BYE sip:126.219.52.41;vbdid=941.29056c13 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 136.46.324.75:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjf05b6f33-c9d2-4606-80d5-1e54fc110d40
From: <sip:13051079265@localphone.com>;tag=514dc3ba-68ed-42ff-9733-bd65b8ebb7c7
To: <sip:10782172281@126.219.52.41>;tag=gK086bb5a7
Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56
CSeq: 13266 BYE
Route: <sip:140.153.72.56;lr;ftag=gK086bb5a7>
Reason: Q.850;cause=16
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 15.6.1
Content-Length:  0


<--- Received SIP response (335 bytes) from UDP:140.153.72.56:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 136.46.324.75:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKPjf05b6f33-c9d2-4606-80d5-1e54fc110d40
From: <sip:13051079265@localphone.com>;tag=514dc3ba-68ed-42ff-9733-bd65b8ebb7c7
To: <sip:10782172281@126.219.52.41>;tag=gK086bb5a7
Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56
CSeq: 13266 BYE
Content-Length: 0
```

Your help will be appreciated !

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458 That might be your issue. Basically apple says they will do things different, i think. I am looking into this issue on Iphones too.

Comment: One-way audio sounds like NAT or firewall. Normally ICE connectivity checks would validate that but VoIP doesn't always use ICE. Can you post the SDP messages?

Comment: Sonus is telling asterisk to use ip 199.199.12.54 for voice communications, but the sip messages are coming from 126.219.52.41. Does the machine have two different ip addresses?

Comment: The machine has only one IP address: 136.46.324.75. The IP that you noticed, namely 199.199.12.56 is not my IP and it doesn't seem to be Localphone's IP either. Localphone appears in the above lines with the IP's: 126.219.52.41 and 140.153.72.56. The IP that you noticed, 199.199.12.56 seems to be located in the US and associated with the local phone number rented from Localphone (+13051079265) which is also located in the US.

Comment: 199.199.12.56 also appears in the Call ID (Call-ID: 793253110_109248450@199.199.12.56). My guess is that it's an American IP associated with the call when it's received by Localphone. Thank you for this interesting catch. I haven't noticed it at all. What do you think is happening ?

Comment: Sonus is telling asterisk to send the voice data to 199.199.12.56. If you dont know where that IP is coming from, that’s probably your one-way audio issue.  I’m not familiar with sonus devices so I don’t know how it discovers ip addresses, but it looks like it’s using the wrong one. You’ll need to check it’s logs and config files to find out.